# Doing networkprocesses on the Main UI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json, asynchronous

My Android App needs some basic data to run. This data is downloaded from a server using JSON. In Xcode I simply used the sendsynchronous request but I noticed that Eclipse gives me a error when i do networking on the main ui.
Found a lot of stuff on asynctask but i want my app to wait till the required data is downloaded (synchronous?).

I tried using asynctask .execute().get() and setting the variables in onPostExecute but when I return the variable I get a NullPointerException. Does someone know how to make this work? I really need this data before the app can run so I want my app to wait till the data is downloaded.

MainActivity calls this:

```
SingletonClass appIDSingleton = SingletonClass.getInstance();
this.ID = appIDSingleton.getAppID();
```

Singleton Class:

```
public String getAppID() {
           try {
            new DownloadAppID().execute(APP_ID_URL).get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           return AppID; //AppID is still NULL (because the download isnt finished yet?)
       }

private class DownloadAppID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println(result);
            AppID = result;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Where you get NullPointerException?

Comment: edited my post. I get the null at the return of the getAppID method

Comment: Where you call this lines ? SingletonClass appIDSingleton = SingletonClass.getInstance();
this.ID = appIDSingleton.getAppID(); :)

Comment: please add the stack trace and point to the exact line. Also where is APP_ID defined?

Comment: the instantiation is called in the MainActivity:
protected String ID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  SingletonClass appIDSingleton = SingletonClass.getInstance();
this.ID = appIDSingleton.getAppID();
  System.out.println(ID);
}

APP_ID is defined in SingletonClass:
public class SingletonClass {
 
 private String AppID;
//( implementation ) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that your `getAppID` method can't return a result that is going to be computed asynchronously.

You could for instance provide a listener to your async task in order to notify when app ID is available:

```
    SingletonClass appIDSingleton = SingletonClass.getInstance();
    appIDSingleton.getAppID(new AppIdDownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void appIDAvailable(String appId) {
            this.ID = appId; 
        }
    });


public void getAppID(AppIdDownloadListener listener) {
    try {
        new DownloadAppID(listener).execute(APP_ID_URL).get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public interface AppIdDownloadListener {
    public void appIDAvailable(String appId);
}

private class DownloadAppID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private AppIdDownloadListener listener;

    public DownloadAppID(AppIdDownloadListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        /* Your stuff here */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
        listener.appIDAvailable(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me! Did it a little different but your answers covers everything! Thanks

Comment: Last question though. Is this the right way to handle the JSON data from the web?

Comment: That sounds OK, though you could probably get rid of this `getAppID` method I guess.